# How to identify the installed version of Sitecore Media Framework of Ooyala?

Tags: version, sitecore

I have upgraded Sitecore Media Framework 1.4 from Media Framework 1.2. I got some warnings on the installation. i.e Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters. I am not sure whether the new version has been upgraded or not. However, I see some differences in the content videos. Got more videos than the existing Media Framework version. I would like to verify on Sitecore What version of Sitecore Media Framework Ooayala Edition installed on my sitecore instance.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance. 
Annadurai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the version of Sitecore Media Framework by looking at the properties of the DLL files (Sitecore.MediaFramework.Ooyala.dll and Sitecore.MediaFramework.dll). The version is located in the Details tab.

If you don't have access to the bin files, you can also have a look at the items under `/sitecore/system/Packages/Installation history/` in the `Core` database.

Also, be sure you have installed the correct framework according to your Sitecore version. See [Sitecore SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Media%20Framework/Ooyala.aspx) for details.